# Anomaly Detection Using Keras - Low Prediction Rate

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I built an Anomaly detection system using Autoencoder, implemented in keras.
My input is a normalized vector with length 13.
My dataset contains about 25,000 non anomaly inputs which dedicated for learning.
I get about 10^-5 MSE after learning with 1-3 epochs.
The problem is that although I get to a small MSE my AE can't detect anomalies good enough..
Model class:

```
class AutoEncoder:
    def __init__(self, inputLen, modelName,Batch,epochs):
        self.modelName       = modelName
        self.DL_BATCH_SIZE   = Batch
        self.DL_EPOCHS       = epochs
        self.DL_LAYER1       = 200
        self.DL_LAYER2       = 150
        self.DL_LAYER3       = 100
        self.DL_LAYEROUT     = 13
        self.DL_LOADMODEL    = None
        #self.DL_SAVEMODEL    = fileConfig.getConfigParam(DL_SAVEMODEL)
        #print(tensorflow.version.VERSION)
        
        
        if self.DL_LOADMODEL == None or self.DL_LOADMODEL == 0:
            my_init = keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=1)
            self.dlModel = keras.models.Sequential()
            
            self.dlModel.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=self.DL_LAYER1, activation='tanh', input_dim=inputLen,kernel_initializer=my_init))
            self.dlModel.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=self.DL_LAYER2, activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=my_init))
            self.dlModel.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=self.DL_LAYER3, activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=my_init))
            self.dlModel.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=self.DL_LAYER2, activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=my_init))
            self.dlModel.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=self.DL_LAYER1, activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=my_init))
            self.dlModel.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=self.DL_LAYEROUT, activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=my_init))
            #sgd = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=0.0005, momentum=0, nesterov=True)
            #adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.005,decay=0.005)
            simple_adam=keras.optimizers.Adam()
            self.dlModel.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=simple_adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
        else:
            self.dlModel = keras.models.load_model(self.DL_LOADMODEL + ".h5")
```

After training I find the max reconstruction MSE on a specific dataset of 2500 non anomalies.
Then i test my Anomaly detector and mark as anomaly every input that its reconstruction has more than the max MSE*0.9 value.
find max error:

```
N = len(non_anomaly)
max_se = 0.0;
max_ix = 0
second_max=0
predicteds = kerasNN.predict(non_anomaly)
for i in range(N):
  curr_se = np.square(np.subtract(non_anomaly[i],predicteds[i])).mean()
  if curr_se > max_se:
    second_max=max_se
    max_se = curr_se; 
    max_ix = i
```

Testing the model:

```
    predicteds=kerasNN.predict(x_train_temp)

#errors vector generation
anomaly_binary_vector = []
i=0
anomalies=0
for x_original,x_reconstructed in zip(x_train_temp,predicteds):
    MSE=np.square(np.subtract(x_original,x_reconstructed)).mean()
    if(MSE>=0.95*max_se):
        anomaly_binary_vector.append(1)
    else:
        anomaly_binary_vector.append(0)
    i+=1
```

Output:

```
anomalies 2419
not detected anomalies   2031
non anomaly but marked as anomaly   2383
percentage of non anomaly instructions that marked as anomalies out of non anomalies : 0.3143384777733808
percentage of  anomaly instructions that wasn't detected out of anomalies: 0.8396031417941298
```

How can I Improve My anomaly detection?

Comment: Have you trained your model with normal data as well or has it only seen anomalies?

Comment: You should plot a histogram of your anomaly scores, with the labeled anomalies and non-anomalies colored differently. Then you see your models ability to discriminate between the two

Answer (score 0):

A problem can be that you are "blowing up" you're autoencoder. You have an input of 13 and than map that to 200, 150, 100 and 13 again. There is no bottleneck in the network where it has to learn a compressed representation of the input.

Maybe try 13 -> 6 -> 4 -> 6 -> 13 or something like that. Than it lears a compressed representation and the task to reconstruct the input is not trivial anymore.

Additionally play around with other hyperparameters like the activation function. Maybe change it to 'relu' in the intermediate models.

Comment: Firstly , thanks for your answer. I dont get an improvement by changing the width of the layers to 13->6>4>6>13. and by changing the "middl" layers to relu... doesn't 10^-5 MSE is accurate enough to detect anomalies?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the data. Have you tried some other classifiers for outlier detection like "Isolation Forest" or "Oneclass SVM"? If so how was the performance for those? Maybe the data is just not suited for this kind of task

Comment: No . I will try . by not suited for thjis kind of task you mean anomaly detection in general or AE in particular?

Comment: Yes, I mean anomaly detection in general. But I guess if it at least somewhat works with the other techniques, there could be ways go get it to work with AE as well.